# How to aggregate on datetime column in Spark/SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

How can I aggregate the mean values for every 10 min using column B datetime.

input

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo",
          "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo"],
     "B": ["2013-01-01 01:01:00", "2013-01-01 01:03:00", "2013-01-01 01:06:00", 
           "2013-01-01 01:07:00", "2013-01-01 01:10:00", "2013-01-01 01:13:00", 
           "2013-01-01 01:16:00", "2013-01-01 01:19:00", 
           "2013-01-02 02:01:00", "2013-01-02 02:03:00", "2013-01-02 02:06:00", 
           "2013-01-02 02:07:00", "2013-01-02 02:10:00", "2013-01-02 02:13:00", 
           "2013-01-02 02:16:00", "2013-01-02 02:19:00"],
     "C": np.random.randn(16),
    })
```

Code

```
SELECT A,B,AVG(C) as C_mean
FROM df1
GROUP BY (DATEPART(MINUTE, [B])/10)
```

Expected output

```
2013-01-01 01:10:00  20
2013-01-01 01:20:00 30
2013-01-02 02:10:00 10
2013-01-02 02:20:00 20
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DATEPART is a product specific function.)

Comment: Your sample data could include at least a couple of different dates.

Comment: @jarlh spark.sql. Ok let me update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways you can achieve is to implicitly create the `groupby` column you require - which in this case is a `10 Minute Interval` as below -

Once you have the required column , its pure aggregation afterwards

#### Data Preparation & Time Interval Creation

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo",
          "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foo", "foo"],
     "B": ["2013-01-01 01:01:00", "2013-01-01 01:03:00", "2013-01-01 01:06:00", 
           "2013-01-01 01:07:00", "2013-01-01 01:10:00", "2013-01-01 01:13:00", 
           "2013-01-01 01:16:00", "2013-01-01 01:19:00", 
           "2013-01-02 02:01:00", "2013-01-02 02:03:00", "2013-01-02 02:06:00", 
           "2013-01-02 02:07:00", "2013-01-02 02:10:00", "2013-01-02 02:13:00", 
           "2013-01-02 02:16:00", "2013-01-02 02:19:00"],
     "C": np.random.randn(16),
    })


sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)\
             .withColumn("B",F.to_timestamp(F.col("B"),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))\
             .withColumn("unix_ts",F.unix_timestamp(F.col("B")))\
             .withColumn("time_interval",F.col("unix_ts") - (F.col('unix_ts') % 600))\
             .withColumn("time_interval_dt",F.from_unixtime("time_interval"))\
             .orderBy(*['A','time_interval','B'])

sparkDF.createOrReplaceTempView("sparkDF")
```

#### Data Creation - Spark SQL

```
imm_res = sql.sql("""
WITH IMM_RES AS (
SELECT
    A,
    B,
    C,
    unix_ts,
    unix_ts - (unix_ts % 600) as time_interval,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_ts - (unix_ts % 600)) as time_interval_dt
FROM(
    SELECT
        A,
        TO_TIMESTAMP(B,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') as B,
        C,
        UNIX_TIMESTAMP(TO_TIMESTAMP(B,'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')) as unix_ts
    FROM SPARKDF
    )
)

SELECT * FROM IMM_RES

""")

imm_res.show()

+---+-------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
|  A|                  B|                   C|   unix_ts|time_interval|   time_interval_dt|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
|bar|2013-01-01 01:03:00| -1.1074768756488491|1356982380|   1356982200|2013-01-01 01:00:00|
|bar|2013-01-01 01:07:00| -1.3904690748604658|1356982620|   1356982200|2013-01-01 01:00:00|
|bar|2013-01-01 01:13:00| 0.10823010338926187|1356982980|   1356982800|2013-01-01 01:10:00|
|bar|2013-01-02 02:03:00|-0.42164831031239086|1357072380|   1357072200|2013-01-02 02:00:00|
|bar|2013-01-02 02:07:00|-0.10930060840368964|1357072620|   1357072200|2013-01-02 02:00:00|
|bar|2013-01-02 02:13:00| -1.7879231287345696|1357072980|   1357072800|2013-01-02 02:10:00|
|foo|2013-01-01 01:01:00| -1.0260782342032664|1356982260|   1356982200|2013-01-01 01:00:00|
|foo|2013-01-01 01:06:00|1.415566010814215...|1356982560|   1356982200|2013-01-01 01:00:00|
|foo|2013-01-01 01:10:00| -1.0542860688409124|1356982800|   1356982800|2013-01-01 01:10:00|
|foo|2013-01-01 01:16:00| 0.14101008568224452|1356983160|   1356982800|2013-01-01 01:10:00|
|foo|2013-01-01 01:19:00| -1.0361973194717629|1356983340|   1356982800|2013-01-01 01:10:00|
|foo|2013-01-02 02:01:00|  0.9224421915087914|1357072260|   1357072200|2013-01-02 02:00:00|
|foo|2013-01-02 02:06:00| -0.5560569181896606|1357072560|   1357072200|2013-01-02 02:00:00|
|foo|2013-01-02 02:10:00| -0.9397516560457578|1357072800|   1357072800|2013-01-02 02:10:00|
|foo|2013-01-02 02:16:00| -0.5107170960172278|1357073160|   1357072800|2013-01-02 02:10:00|
|foo|2013-01-02 02:19:00|   1.975558541342583|1357073340|   1357072800|2013-01-02 02:10:00|
+---+-------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

#### Aggregation

```
imm_res.createOrReplaceTempView("IMM_RES")

sql.sql("""
SELECT 
    time_interval_dt,
    AVG(C) as C_mean
FROM IMM_RES
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
""").show()

+-------------------+--------------------+
|   time_interval_dt|              C_mean|
+-------------------+--------------------+
|2013-01-01 01:00:00| -0.8809706570278749|
|2013-01-01 01:10:00| -0.4603107998102922|
|2013-01-02 02:00:00|-0.04114091134923745|
|2013-01-02 02:10:00|  -0.315708334863743|
+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: this is very interesting. Is it possible to create this time_interval_dt with SQL command?

Comment: SELECT *, mean(C) OVER (
        PARTITION BY A
        ORDER BY CAST(B AS timestamp) 
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS mean FROM df

Comment: I can't write it as answer because i didn't test, but it's very close to what you need i believe.

Comment: Added the data preparation part using `SPARKSQL`